# Installing Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I have a laptop with a 740m graphics card and I've tried installing drivers from the additional drivers program from the system settings but when I activate and reboot the driver says it's not being used so that didn't work. My second option was to download directly from the NVIDIA driver website and run it from the ternimal via lightdm stop command and it gives me an error saying my GPU isn't support when I try to run it even though my card is officially supported on the NVIDIA website.

Should I continue intsalling the diver from the NVIDIA website even though it gives error messages or something else. Any help would be appreciated though i'm still new here :)

Comment: Do you have optimus technology on your laptop?

Comment: Yes I do have an optimus card

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia
```

If you have 32-bit applications like Wine

```
sudo apt-get install virtualgl-libs:i386
```

Reboot or re-login to apply the group changes
If you'd like to run a program on the nvidia card now, use the optirun program:

```
optirun firefox &
```

Comment: E: Type 'ain' is not known on line 3 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bumblebee-stable-precise.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
kieran@KieranPC:~$ sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package bumblebee is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Comment: Package bumblebee-nvidia is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Type 'ain' is not known on line 3 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bumblebee-stable-precise.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Package 'bumblebee' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'bumblebee-nvidia' has no installation candidate
                                                            Got these after doing sudo apt-get update